# How can I get the insertion point to be at the end of the line?

Tags: java

I am scanning something in and when there is a prompt to type something the insertion point always goes to the next line.

Example

Enter your answer to problem 1 - (A, B, C, or D)

B

I want to B to be at the end like this in the console.

Enter your answer to problem 1 - (A, B, C, or D) B

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
System.out.println("Enter your answer to problem 1 - (A, B, C, or D)");
```

Use

```
System.out.print("Enter your answer to problem 1 - (A, B, C, or D) ");
```

The difference between the two methods is that `println`

> Prints a String and then terminate the line.

But `print` just

> Prints a string.

([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html))

By 'terminate' the javadoc means that it prints the system-defined line separator string (which in some, but not all cases, is the `\n` character), which tells your terminal window to go to the next line before you are grabbing your `Scanner` input.

Answer (score 0):

Without code it is a bit hard to say *exactly* what is happening for you, but my guess is that you are using something like this

```
System.out.println("Some Prompt: ");
Scanner.next();
```

When you say `println()` the cursor automatically moves to the next line. You just want to print on a single line so instead use

```
System.out.print("Some Prompt: ") // Notice print instead of println
Scanner.next();
```